Consulta con ajax
Buenas espero y me puedan contestar estoy trabajando con ajax para hacer una consulta y resulta y pasa que cuando inspecciono a traves de console log el me muestra la consulta que es me muestre y traiga un array de todos los docentes y el docente especifico pero resulta que aunque me muestre todo en la consola al inspeccionar no me lo esta mostrando dentro del selector asignado para mostrar por lo queno se que hacer por cierto el selector esta dentro de un modal aqui esta el codigo
    // Agregar el evento de clic a los botones de editar en la tabla
    $('.boton-editar').on('click', function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        // Obtener los datos de la asignatura desde el botón de editar
        var idAsignatura = $(this).data('id-asignatura');
        var nombreAsignatura = $(this).data('nombre-asignatura');
        var idDocente = $(this).data('id-docente');
        var año = $(this).data('año');

        // Llenar el formulario con los datos de la asignatura seleccionada
        $('#nombre_asignatura').val(nombreAsignatura);
        $('#año').val(año);
        // Guardar el ID de la asignatura en un campo oculto para usarlo en el formulario
        $('#id_asignatura').val(idAsignatura);
        // Asignar el valor del ID del docente al selector de docentes
        // Desplegar el modal
        $('#modalEditarAsignatura').modal('show');

        // Realizar la solicitud AJAX para obtener el nombre y apellido del docente
        // después de que el modal se haya mostrado completamente
        $('#modalEditarAsignatura').on('shown.bs.modal', function() {
            $('#id_docente').val(idDocente);
            console.log(idDocente);
            $.ajax({
                url: 'obtener_docentes.php',
                method: 'GET',
                data: { id_docente: idDocente }, // Pasar el idDocente si se necesita un docente específico
                dataType: 'json',
                success: function(data) {
                    console.log("Respuesta del servidor:", data); // Ver la respuesta completa del servidor
                    console.log("Estructura de data:", data); // Verificar la estructura de data
                    if (data.error) {
                        console.error(data.error);
                        swal.fire({
                            icon: 'error',
                            title: 'Error',
                            text: 'No se pudo cargar los docentes. Por favor, inténtalo de nuevo.',
                        });
                    } else {
                         $.each(data.todosLosDocentes, function(i, docente) {
                            var option = $('<option></option>');

                            // Asigna el valor y el texto de la opción.
                            option.val(docente.id);
                            option.text(docente.nombre);
                            // Marca la opción como seleccionada si corresponde al docente seleccionado.
                            if (docente.id == data.docenteSeleccionado.id) {
                            option.prop('selected', true);
                    }
                    $('#id_docente').append(option);
                }
            )}
        },
                error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                    console.error("Error en la solicitud AJAX:", textStatus, errorThrown); // Ver el error
                    swal.fire({
                        icon: 'error',
                        title: 'Error',
                        text: 'No se pudo cargar los docentes. Por favor, inténtalo de nuevo.',
                    });
                }
            });
        });
    });```



$('#id_docente').append(option); muévelo una línea arriba, que quede justo debajo de option.prop('selected', true);
